# EasyRedmine rake redmine:email:receive_imap doesn't work

Tags: nginx, debian, ruby, redmine, unicorn

I'm trying to use redmine:email:recive_imap rake task on my company's Easyredmine Server to fetch emails from our server mail's adress, but when I launch the command:

```
rake redmine:email:receive_imap RAILS_ENV="production" host=mail.mycompany port=143 starttls=true username=username@mycompany.com password=XXXXXX
```

I obtain the following result :

```
/srv/redmine/public_html/lib/redmine/imap.rb:34:in `check'
/srv/redmine/public_html/lib/tasks/email.rake:117:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/srv/redmine/public_html/app/models/mailer.rb:438:in `with_synched_deliveries'
/srv/redmine/public_html/lib/tasks/email.rake:116:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => redmine:email:receive_imap
```

Can anyone help me?
Thank you.

Comment: I missede the full log :

rake aborted!
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_write: unknown state
/srv/redmine/public_html/lib/redmine/imap.rb:34:in `check'
/srv/redmine/public_html/lib/tasks/email.rake:117:in `block (4 levels) in '
/srv/redmine/public_html/app/models/mailer.rb:438:in `with_synched_deliveries'
/srv/redmine/public_html/lib/tasks/email.rake:116:in `block (3 levels) in '
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `'
Tasks: TOP => redmine:email:receive_imap

Answer (score 0):

Usually port 143 is the non-encrypted imap port. Try using port 993 and check the email server to sure it's open.